# Calling all bloggers!

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog

Do you have any of the following qualities?

- A love for writing [long and details answers](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/10/maximizing-the-lifetime-of-your-ssd/) to common Super User problems
- A desire to [test, document, and share](http://blog.superuser.com/2013/03/14/cable-vs-dsl-which-was-better/) with fellow Super Users [awesome products](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/08/01/keyboard-capersa-field-guide-to-keyboards/) (sometimes for FREE!)
- An interest in the weird, funny, or just [plain cool](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/) technological subjects out there

Then **WE WANT YOU!!!**  We're looking to get some new fresh blood into the blog and produce some high quality content.  Here's a quick guide on how to get started, and what to expect:

### Where do I get started?

First create an account for the blog.  To do this, you simply go to [blog.superuser.com/wp-admin](http://blog.superuser.com/wp-admin) and log in using your OpenID that you use for the blog (similar to joining a new SE site).  After that, you'll be able to comment on posts, but not create any new posts.  If you want to start creating a post check out the Super User Blog chat room and ping either me (@Kronos) or @Nhinkle so we can get you started.

Also be sure to check out and join our [Trello](https://trello.com/b/xdPQplr4/su-blog-posts-scheduling) board.  It's a little dusty at times, but we try to keep things as up to date as possible in there.  It's a great tool to know who's working on what.

### I've got an idea I'd like to blog about, how do I start?

Create the idea on the Trello board, and talk to either Nhinkle or Me about it.  This isn't exactly necessary, but we've been doing this long enough that we'll be able to give some feedback on whether it's an on-topic post or not.

From there you'll simply use the editor within blog's WordPress engine.  When you think you're done, ping either me or Nhinkle and we go over it, and schedule it for being published

### I'm an unimaginative being and have no ideas, therefore I can't be of any use to you

WRONG.  Just because you can't think of something right now, doesn't mean later down the road you won't be able to either.  Plus, we're going to restart the Question of the Month posts, and you can do one of those.  You can also look for interesting questions from Super User and blog about them on your own.  I promise, if you sit down for just a few minutes something will come to mind about  what you can blog about.

### Wait, blog posts can be on/off topic?

Yes.  Although wide in subject matter, there are still areas that we really can't/shouldn't explore within the blog.  I know you love your cat, and want to blog about it's heroic deeds as the [neighborhood serial killer](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/cats_actually_kill), but we just can't blog about it here.  You'll have to find somewhere else to do that.

If you have any question about what you can and can't blog... you guessed it, just talk to Nhinkle or I and we'll gladly help you out.

### How often do I need to contribute to the blog?/Is there an expected amount of posts I'm asked to do?

This is a voluntary thing, and therefore we understand that you're schedules are busy.  You're not expected to give us a certain amount of posts or to be under specific deadlines each week.  If you do however sign up for a post, we do hope that you'll get that post done in time to keep the flow of posts coming.  If you can't make it, please let us know a head of time so we can plan accordingly.

### Is there a regular schedule to posting on the blog?

We're shooting for at least one post a month, and at most once every two weeks starting out.  This helps us keeps things on par with that quality that we've already been producing, and doesn't add as much pressure on the bloggers themselves.

### Are there other ways I can contribute to the blog?

Unless you're a company and would like us to review your products, right now all we need are contributors to the blog.  That does not mean you'll only be writing posts.  We hope you'll also help look at others posts and give positive feedback.

### What's the purpose of this dumb blog anyways?

Ultimately it's to give back to the Super User community.  We want to highlight awesome questions/answers that Super Users are creating.  We also want to create content that can be linked to within questions.  Finally we want to create content that Super Users ultimately enjoy reading about.  Take a look at some of our previous posts to get a better idea.

Feel free to contact us with any other questions that you may have.

Comment: Can one reference link to his site at the end of the blog post? I mean one reason why someone would post on superuser's blog for **free** is to get some traffic to his site and make some money

Comment: @Fischer check [this meta post](http://meta.superuser.com/q/2482/47225).  My inclination is that this is *ok* but depends on how you do it.

Comment: Thanks sir for the link :)

Comment: @Fischer also the main goal of contributing to the blog is the same as contributing to the site.  You wouldn't (at least shouldn't) add links to your blogs with every post on SE would you?

Comment: i know and i agree, i was just checking if it's against the rules or not :)

Comment: @Fischer you're always welcome to put a link to your site on your profile though.

Comment: I think a byline also wouldn't be a problem: *Fischer is the Wile E Coyote professor of ACME product testing at the eXcellence Kriegsmarine College of Demolitions. You can read more of his incoherent ramblings [on his blog](http://fischerblog.example.com) or on [Twitter](http://twitter.example.com/fischer).* Not sure about more prominent links though. They shouldn't lead to worse posts ("This is just the teaser, continue on my blog") in any way.

Comment: @DanielBeck I like this idea.  It's similar to "guest posts" from other blogs (i.e. [lifehacker.com](http://lifehacker.com/5802838/how-to-maximize-the-life-of-your-ssd?asid=26ada452))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling all bloggers.... Again](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/11050/calling-all-bloggers-again)