# How can I create just an answer without a question (blog)?

Tags: support, feature-request

I know this is a question answer forum, but the last 2 years I've been building three systems (2 computers, old and new, running dolphin and a XPenology NAS) and found some very interesting facts. Which may be very usefull for other people.

**Can I create a blog of some sort, just for posting information?**

Comment: Of course you can create a blog. Somewhere else not on the se network ;)

Comment: http://blog.superuser.com - you can talk to @Kronos or nhinkle about what you'd like to write about and may get permission to post something

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/11050/calling-all-bloggers-again

Answer (score 2):

When you found out something interesting and you think that it may benefit others then you would usually pose a hypothetical question and then answer it with an answer including the information you gathered.

This is perfectly fine and I've done it several times in the past.

There's also a post about this on [Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/), but I couldn't find it right now.