# Collaborating on the Super User site blog

Tags: support, superuser-blog

I just read [Calling all bloggers.... Again](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11050/calling-all-bloggers-again) today. I am a school student who is really interested in tech and my holidays started today so I think that I might contribute a few articles.

The problem is that my knowledge is quite limited on a few topics. Let's just say that I might want some feedback or advice from other community members. How do I go about this? Do I ask a meta question?

Comment: You can either just talk to us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access), or write up a draft of what you want to blog about on Google Docs and link to it in a meta question with the "Anyone who has a link can comment" permission enabled.

Comment: @allquixotic Thanks!!

Comment: @JakeGould I think feedback may include more areas than SU allows for questions, such as comments on word choice and style.